# Hidden properties of skills?

Tags: diablo-iii

Playing with my Demon Hunter a bit, it seems like a lot of skills have hidden properties which are not mentioned in the skill description (even in the expanded one).

For instance, [Hungering Arrow](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/hungering-arrow) ricochets off walls and obstacles back towards a monster, in practice giving it a higher damage. [Evasive Fire](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/evasive-fire) greatly increases the projectile speed, making it more efficient for taking down ranged enemies moving laterally (like wasps), etc.

Is there anywhere, in-game or out-of-game, I can see these "hidden attributes" listed? Or is experimentation the only way?

Comment: I've also noticed that Hungering Arrow can "double back" on a mob if it pierces through them. Quite nice :)

Comment: I would wager these are less "hidden properties" and more "game knowledge". Knowing that Deadly Reach is faster than One Hundred Fists isn't a *property* of the skill, it's just knowledge of the relative speeds of the skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of these types of effects in games are learned from simply playing the game more. I don't envision these being available from an official Blizzard source, since it would be quite overwhelming for most to make use of the information - save the most advanced players.

The other side effect of this is that it encourages players to explore more skills and  mechanics to master the game.

Comment: Don't forget to make use of advanced tool tips and the 'details' section of the character sheet for more clues.